# Gcloud List Output Format Not Columnar

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Any `list` command in `gcloud` shell is returning in an unexpected, harder to read format.
Example: From doc: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/it-ops/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with

> Let's start off by formatting a simple command that you are already
> familiar with that lists the projects to which you have access:
> `gcloud projects list`
>
> ```
>     PROJECT_ID            NAME          PROJECT_NUMBER
>     canvas-syntax-130823  scesproject2  346904393285
>     windy-bearing-129522  scesproject1  222844913538
> ```

When I try this I always get format:

```
    PROJECT_ID: anvas-syntax-130823
    NAME: scesproject2
    PROJECT_NUMBER: 346904393285

    PROJECT_ID: windy-bearing-129522
    NAME: scesproject1
    PROJECT_NUMBER: 222844913538
```

This format is harder to read and navigate especially for longer outputs.
Any idea why I am getting output in this format?
I tried with different instances, different accounts, it is not tied to any config I would have.

I know about the `--format` options, I would just like to understand why and where is the "tabular" default view gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLI has an option to make output easier for screen readers to process.

To disable that feature:

```
gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader false
```

To enable that feature:

```
gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader true
```

This link provides more information:

[gcloud config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set)

Comment: Awesome! That was it. Is this a new default?

Comment: @DDan - not that I know of. Do you have any installed screen readers on your computer? I have seen this mentioned before. Perhaps Google is auto-detecting something installed on your computer.